# Set text for Editext from Intents not populating

Tags: android, android-edittext

Want to set a text on `EditText` as soon as i get values from `Intents`. I have written `editText.clearFocus()` inside `onResume` and `editText.setOnClickListener` and `editText.addTextChangedListener` inside `onCreate`. Want to know which of these method is causing to override `EditText` text. As i have tried putting code inside `onCreate` and `onResume`. Neither of them are working.

i have tried following code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   binding.editUsername.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //some code
        }
    });
binding.editUsername.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            Utilities.Logd("", "beforeTextChanged called for username");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            //some code
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            Utilities.Logd("", "afterTextChanged called for username");
        }
    });
    if (getIntent() != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(getIntent().getStringExtra(FROM_NOTIFICATIONS))) {
        intentDataFromNotification = getIntent();
    }
    if (getIntent().getStringExtra(GenericConstants.FROM) != null) {
        if (getIntent().getStringExtra(GenericConstants.FROM).equalsIgnoreCase("ForgotUsernameActivity")) {
            if (getIntent().getStringExtra(GenericConstants.USERNAME) != null) {
                binding.editUsername.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra(GenericConstants.USERNAME));
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (PrefManager.getInstance().getUsername().length() > 0) {
            binding.editUsername.setText(PrefManager.getInstance().getUsername());
        }
    }
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    binding.editUsername.clearFocus();
}
```

Comment: It looks like `intent` does not have the extras field or it has the `null` value that's why edit text value is not being set. Please try to add logs in `If` condition.

Comment: i have debbuged this code and i do get values from intent

Answer (score 1):

First of all ensure that your `binding` is correct and done before handling `view` as I don't see that code. Beside this handle `intent` like below, If you have those data inside `intent` then it should work:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent dataIntent = getIntent();

    if(dataIntent != null) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(dataIntent.getStringExtra(FROM_NOTIFICATIONS))) {
            intentDataFromNotification = getIntent();
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(dataIntent.getStringExtra(GenericConstants.FROM)) &&
                dataIntent.getStringExtra(GenericConstants.FROM).equalsIgnoreCase("ForgotUsernameActivity")) {

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(dataIntent.getStringExtra(GenericConstants.USERNAME))) {
                binding.editUsername.setText(dataIntent.getStringExtra(GenericConstants.USERNAME));
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (PrefManager.getInstance().getUsername().length() > 0) {
            binding.editUsername.setText(PrefManager.getInstance().getUsername());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks, this worked. binding was setting text after setting text from intent data.

Comment: @nayanabhoj, if it will help you then please accept the answer and hit upvote. Thanks